# Setup dependencies between IntelliJ Gradle Modules to execute Gradle tasks

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependency-management, build.gradle

I have two IntelliJ Gradle modules in my IntelliJ project and they are jpav-common and jpav-code, respectively. jpav-code have a dependency to jpav-common, so I setup this dependency through Project setting like below.

[image]

But when I try to execute a Gradle task such as testClasses or build, Gradle cannot identify this dependency. Checkout the error message I got.

[image]

Obviously, It seems like my dependency setup is only meaningful inside IntelliJ. (Running JUnit test and compiling using IntelliJ's run configuration works fine.) How can I make Gradle tasks to be aware of this dependency? Do I need to write some code to build.gradle? Where can I find some information about it?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks! I make setting.gradle file on the root of my project by manual following the user guide and it works now.